# RestKit format NSDate before POST

Tags: ios, restkit

In my AppDelegate I initialise the date transformer like this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
[[RKValueTransformer defaultValueTransformer] insertValueTransformer:dateFormatter atIndex:0];
```

Because I get it from my REST server in this format and that works fine as expected. Now in my APP I change a couple of values and then I'd like to send the Object back in a POST ([Using this method more or less](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#post-patch-and-delete-an-object)). However the dates are now NSDates which are sent in this format

```
"2011-03-29T22:00:00Z"
```

Is there a way in Restkit to format the Date when it gets transformed into JSON?

Comment: Where is this code, when is it run compared to other initialisation code?

Comment: Actually this you can do everywhere in your code, but I do it in a static initialisation block

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Did you find a work around for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in this case we ended up changing the server code to the ISO8601DateFormat.

However there is a fix for this Problem. When you put the code above in a general initialisation method (in my case) in the AppDelegate then you'll put your DateFormatter at position 0, but then you initialise your first ObjectMapping (or EntityMapping) and your DateFormatter will be overridden by the Default one... or better not overridden but anticipated.

So, all you need to do is initialising the mapping before adding the DateFormatter which can be done with this line.

```
[RKObjectMapping alloc]; // This ensures you will actually insert at index 0!
```

Actually I had a [similar problem a month later, and there I got the hint to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407436/ios-restkit-date-parsing)